# Using batch scripting, how will I find whether a given file is present in every folder?

Tags: batch-file

I have a root folder "Basic" which has child folders "1", "2" and "3". "1" has sub-folders "11", "12" and "text.txt". Similarly "2" has sub-folders "22", "21" and "text.txt". "3" has "31" and "32".

I need a batch file program to find whether "text.txt" is present in each folder. If it isn't present in a particular root folder "Basic", I want to write the child folder's name in missingfile.txt.

Here is my account - It doesn't work.

```
set value = ""
set exact = ""
cd "C:\Users\bthirumurthy\Desktop\Basic"
dir  "C:\Users\bthirumurthy\Desktop\Basic" /b >> text.txt
for %%a in (text.txt) do (
  if (%%a|="text.txt") (
    dir  C:\Users\bthirumurthy\Desktop\Basic\%%a /b >> C:\Users\bthirumurthy\Desktop\Basic\%%a\result.txt
    for %%b in (result.txt) do (
      if(%%b == "text.txt") (
        set exact = %%b
        set status = 1
      )
      else (
        set missingfile =%%b
        set status = 0
      )
    )
    if (%status% == 1) (
      echo %exact% pass >> pass.txt
    )
    else (
      echo %exact% fail >> Missingfile.txt
    )
    set status = ""
  )
)>>output.txt
```

Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't taken the time to figure out where your script is going wrong. But a simple one-liner from the command line is all that is needed. No need for batch:

```
>missingFile.txt (for /r "C:\Users\bthirumurthy\Desktop\Basic" %F in (.) do @if not exist "%F\test.txt" echo %~fF)
```

Double up all percents if run from within a batch script. (`%` becomes `%%`)

Basically, this one-liner traverses the directory tree starting from the specified root directory (the `for /d /r` loop). For every subdirectory, it checks if the specified file exists in it (or, rather, if it *doesn't* exist there: `if not exist ...`). If the file doesn't exist, the corresponding subdirectory's full path is logged into `missingfile.txt`. Actually, the path is simply `echo`ed (`echo %~fF`), but the entire loop's output has been redirected (the `>missingFile.txt` at the beginning of the line), so, as a result, `echo` writes to the file.

***EDIT - a slightly simpler variation***

```
>missingFile.txt (for /r "C:\Users\bthirumurthy\Desktop\Basic" %F in (test.txt) do @if not exist "%F" echo %~dpF)
```

The FOR /R loop doesn't check if the file exists unless there is a wildcard in the IN() clause. Without a wildcard it simply walks the directory tree and builds a path with the file name in each directory.